# Why does locking slow down this sequential file parser?

Tags: c++, c++11, locking, pthreads

I wrote a simple reader and parser for a graph file format. The problem is that it is incredibly slow. Here are the relevant methods:

```
Graph METISGraphReader::read(std::string path) {
    METISParser parser(path);
    std::pair<int64_t, int64_t> header = parser.getHeader();
    int64_t n = header.first;
    int64_t m = header.second;

    Graph G(n);

    node u = 0;
    while (parser.hasNext()) {
        u += 1;
        std::vector<node> adjacencies = parser.getNext();
        for (node v : adjacencies) {
            if (! G.hasEdge(u, v)) { 
                G.insertEdge(u, v);
            }
        }
    }
    return G;
}

std::vector<node> METISParser::getNext() {
    std::string line;
    bool comment = false;
    do {
        comment = false;
        std::getline(this->graphFile, line);
        // check for comment line starting with '%'
        if (line[0] == '%') {
            comment = true;
            TRACE("comment line found");
        } else {
            return parseLine(line);
        }

    } while (comment);
}

static std::vector<node> parseLine(std::string line) {
    std::stringstream stream(line);
    std::string token;
    char delim = ' ';
    std::vector<node> adjacencies;

    // split string and push adjacent nodes
    while (std::getline(stream, token, delim)) {
        node v = atoi(token.c_str());
        adjacencies.push_back(v);
    }
    return adjacencies;
}
```

To diagnose why it is so slow, I ran it in a profiler (Apple Instruments). The results were surprising: It's slow because of locking overhead. The program spends over 90% of its time in `pthread_mutex_lock` and `_pthread_cond_wait`.

[image: Instruments]

I have no idea where the locking overhead comes from, but I need to get rid of it. Can you suggest next steps?

EDIT: See the call stack expanded for `_pthread_con_wait`. I cannot figure out the source of the locking overhead by looking at this:

[image]

Comment: @KonradRudolph  I read from a file, a `std::ifstream`. Why do you think I read from stdin?

Comment: Hmm, (why) do you link your code against OpenMP? Does log4cxx bring this dependency?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Because there are `#pragma omp parallel` annotations in many other parts of the project. But not in the parser. Also, a library is linked which depends on the `-fopenmp` linker flag being set.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The library is not log4cxx but a parallel graph data structure library.

Comment: I gathered as much. You *use* log4cxx though so I thought it might come from there. I’m just trying to understand the information, and trying out things. Are you sure that while your parser code is running no other code is running *concurrently* in another thread? What happens when you comment out `TRACE`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I commented out TRACE from the code above, but the overhead remains the same. None of my other code is running concurrently in another thread.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the call stack on the _pthread_cond_wait and pthread_mutex_lock calls to find out where the locking calls are invoked from.

As a guess I'm going to say it's in all the unnecessary heap allocations you're doing.  The heap is a thread safe resource and on this platform the thread safety could be provided via mutexes.

Comment: Have a look at the expanded call stack above. Where do I do the unnecessary heap allocation?

Comment: The locking is done in the OpenMP framework, which is outside the code you have presented here.  You are doing more allocations than you need to in terms of the temporary strings and vectors you create, but they are small potatoes compared to whatever you're doing in OpenMP.

Comment: "You are doing more allocations than you need to in terms of the temporary strings and vectors you create" Probably, but these allocations are on the stack, arent't they?

Comment: The objects are on the stack, but those collections allocate storage for their contents from default allocator, which allocates memory from the heap.

Comment: My anecdotal experience with OSX is that the standard memory allocator has horrid performance in multi-threaded contexts. It seems like in your case the use of OpenMP is forcing the use of the thread-aware allocator.

Comment: I concur, I have observed bad performance on OSX's heap allocator due to locking.

Comment: @bluescarni The parser is also horribly slow on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

All functions that read data from an `istream` will lock a `mutex,` read data from a `streambuf` and unlock the `mutex`. To eliminate that overhead, read the file directly from the `streambuf` instead of the `istream` and don't use `stringstream` to parse the data.

Here is a version of `getline` that uses `streambuf` instead of `istream`

```
bool fastGetline(streambuf* sb, std::string& t)
{
    t.clear();
    for(;;) {
        int c = sb->sbumpc();
        switch (c) {
        case '\n':
            return true;
        case '\r':
            if(sb->sgetc() == '\n')
                sb->sbumpc();
            return true;
        case EOF:
            return !t.empty();
        default:
            t += (char)c;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try to implement my parser using `fastGetline` tomorrow and we'll see if it works.

Comment: If there is a `'\r'` **not** followed by an `'\n'` then `fastGetline` still terminates. I believe it would be better to push_back that `'\r'` and continue reading. Although, it is a matter of judgement how to handle standalone `'\r'`s. An interesting answer anyhow.

Comment: @Ali Standalone `'\r'` was used as end-of-line on Mac until about ten years ago.

Comment: @user763305 I construct the streambuf with `buf = file.rdbuf()`. `fastGetline` reads two lines correctly but then `sb->sbumpc()` fails with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS:Could not access memory`. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to refresh the buffer somehow?

Comment: @cls Try constructing a sentry object before using the streambuf: `istream::sentry se(is, true); streambuf* sb = is.rdbuf();`. Construct the sentry object before you start using the streambuf. Destroy the sentry object when you are done with the streambuf. (Probably easiest by keeping the sentry on the stack.)